# Why did not save multiple images in to the table in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

In my Laravel app I have form to save multiple images to save uploads table, my form as following,

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            {{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group row required">
            <div class="field" align="left" >
            <h3>Upload  images</h3>
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            </div>
</div>
```

and jquery for image,

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $(".files").on("change", function(e) {
      var clickedButton = this;
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter(clickedButton);
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
          });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
 </script>
```

and controller store function is,

```
$photos = $request->file('files');

        if (!is_array($photos)) {
            $photos = [$photos];
        }

        if (!is_dir($this->photos_path)) {
            mkdir($this->photos_path, 0777);
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
            $photo = $photos[$i];
            $name = sha1(date('YmdHis') . str_random(30));
            $save_name = $name . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $resize_name = $name . str_random(2) . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($photo)
                ->resize(250, null, function ($constraints) {
                    $constraints->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save($this->photos_path . '/' . $resize_name);

            $photo->move($this->photos_path, $save_name);

            $upload = new Upload();
            $upload->filename = $save_name;
            $upload->resized_name = $resize_name;
            $upload->original_name = basename($photo->getClientOriginalName());
            $upload->vehicle_id = $vehicle->id;
            $upload->save();
```

but when I attach 4 images in above form. it is saving only one image. that attach to first input file. why other images are not saving to table. how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should either remove `multiple` attribute from file inputs, or use just one file input with `multiple` attribute. Because `multiple` attribute makes a single file input capable of upload multiple files at once by selecting multiple files in the file browse dialog box.

In your controller you should not use `$request->file(...)` because it retrieves a single file not an array of files. Instead use `$request->images` and change the name of your file inputs from `files[]` to `images[]` to prevent conflict with `$request` own property named 'files'.

Comment: I remove multiple attribute from the file input. but not success. but I need 4 image input buttons here in my application. how can fix this problem?

Comment: @banda I updated my answer. check if it solves the problem.

Comment: can you give me cording here according to my answer